# C# Winspool.drv "Cannot open printer"

Tags: winapi, printing

I'm having a problem calling Winspool.drv "OpenPrinter" when I run my program in standard user acccount. But when I ran my program in Administrator account. It can properly execute API call.

I am trying to call OpenPrinter using this API

```
[DllImport("WinSpool.drv", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe bool OpenPrinter (string pPrinterName, int* phPrinter, void* pDefault);
```

and implementing it using this code

```
static unsafe int CSOpenPrinter(string printerName)
{
    bool bResult;
    int hPrinter;
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS pd = new PRINTER_DEFAULTS();
    //int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(pd);
    //IntPtr pdPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
    //pd.pDatatype = null;
    //pd.pDevMode = null;
    pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS;

    bResult = OpenPrinter(printerName, &hPrinter, &pd);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("bResult: " + bResult);
    if (!bResult)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Cannot open printer '" +
                                        printerName + "' " +
                                        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
    return hPrinter;
}
```

Ok again, that code works perfectly when I try to make my program "Run As Administrator". How do I make my application run as a Administrator without right clicking on the application and selecting "Run As Administrator"?

I believe this is a UAC problem, but can you give me an Idea how to solve this? Is adding app.manifest will help? Can you give me an exampple?

Best to all

Comment: Do you actually need `PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS`?  If you just want to print use `PRINTER_ACCESS_USE`.

Comment: I am disabling the printer as my client wants it. I am not sure why PRINTER_ACCESS_USE does not work. This the right value for PRINTER_ACCESS_USE right? PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = 0x00008 - it does not work

Comment: The value is correct.  If you're disabling the printer you probably do need `PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS` and you will need to add a manifest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: awesome! Just what I did! Might want to make that as an answer?

Comment: It already has been [posted as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10812638/588306).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the printer? Your code is asking for full access and so requires admin access.

If you just want to use the printer, request `PRINTER_ACCESS_USE` access instead.

If it is actually an admin process, then [add an appropriate manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to the executable to tell windows that it needs admin access.

Comment: I am disabling the printer as my client wants it. I am not sure why PRINTER_ACCESS_USE does not work. This the right value for PRINTER_ACCESS_USE right? PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = 0x00008 - it does not work

Comment: @JaysonRagasa: You can't change printer settings with PRINTER_ACCESS_USE.  You need PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS and a manifest for your EXE telling Windows it needs elevated privileges, as Deanna said.

Answer (score 0):

Add manifest file to your project. Like [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/7987/making-a-net-app-run-on-vista-with-administrator-priviledges/)